# Short way to write or in python

Tags: python

I have this code:

table is a list.

```
if 'ping' in table or 'pong' in table:
    # Do something here
```

Is there a shorter way to write this?
I don't want to have table duplicated in the if statement.

Comment: Why do you want a shorter way of doing this? This way is fine. It is readable and efficient. Do you expect the number of items you need to check to grow indefinitely?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set.intersection`:

```
if {'ping', 'pong'}.intersection(table):
    # Do something here
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `map`:

```
>>> table = 'pong'
>>> if any(map(lambda pattern: pattern in table, ['ping', 'pong'])):
...     print('found!')
...
found!
```

or:

```
>>> table = 'pong'
>>> if any(pattern in table for pattern in ['ping', 'pong'])):
...     print('found!')
...
found!
```

Comment: Nice suboptimal answer to a blatant duplicate question.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thank you!

Comment: @AndrasDeak in this case, the optimal answer is what the OP has already, as far as I am concerned